# How you say "Is this seat free?" in German

Tags: english-to-german

How you say "Is this seat free?" In german

Comment: I voted to close this question as "Unclear what you're asking". I cannot infer from the question what the specific problem in translating the phrase is. As such I think it's a question not answerable in a specific manner.

Comment: Simple translation requests are off-topic here. Please explain what exactly is your concern.

Comment: I don't find that this is a translation problem.  Here we have a fixed situational formula and one has to know what standard   formulas  are used in the other language.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For example like this:

> - Ist dieser Platz / Sitz frei?
> - Sitzt hier jemand?

Comment: Oder: Ist hier noch frei?

Answer (score 3):

You could as well ask if the seat is *not* free. From my experience I hear this a lot more on my daily commute to the office:

> Sitzt hier schon jemand?

Which would mean something along this line: "Is someone already sitting here?" Or "Is this seat already taken?"

Comment: Like in English where you'd start with the phrase _"Excuse me, ..."_ before asking if the seat it taken, it is also common to do the same in German to be polite: _"Entschuldigung, ist dieser Platz noch frei?"_